Mocked database cursor context manager missing the '__enter__'
I have created a database fixture
@pytest.fixture
def mock_db(mocker):
    """Fixture for setting up a mock database connection."""
    mock_cursor = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock_cursor.__enter__.return_value = mock_cursor # <- the __enter__ is here!
    mock_cursor.__exit__ = mocker.Mock()
    mock_cursor.execute = mocker.MagicMock()

    mock_db = mocker.Mock(spec=Importer)
    mock_db.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor
    return mock_db

A simplyfied version of my test looks like this
def test_drop_import_table(mock_db, mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(Importer,
                        'cursor',
                        new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock,
                        return_value=mock_db.cursor)
    importer = Importer()

    importer.drop_import_table()

    drop_table_call = mock_db.cursor.return_value.execute.call_args_list[0]
    assert "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import_table;" in drop_table_call[0][0]

A simplified version of the method is
    def drop_import_table(self):
        """A temporary table for the raw scan file to be imported to"""
        drop_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `import_table`;"
        with self.cursor as c:
            c.execute(drop_table)

I believe that I have mocked the __enter__, __exit__, and execute methods of the cursor object within my Importer class.
I am expecting the mock cursor to act as a context manager
It seems that I have misunderstood something. Would someone enlighten me please?
The test result is
____________________________ test_drop_import_table ____________________________

mock_db = <Mock spec='Importer' id='140115868741072'>
mocker = <pytest_mock.plugin.MockerFixture object at 0x7f6f44b99270>

    def test_drop_import_table(mock_db, mocker):
        mocker.patch.object(Importer,
                            'cursor',
                            new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock,
                            return_value=mock_db.cursor)
        importer = Importer()
    
>       importer.create_import_table()

tests/import_class_tests.py:24: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <database.import_manager.Importer object at 0x7f6f44956f50>

    def create_import_table(self):
        """A temporary table for the raw scan file to be imported to"""
        drop_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `import_table`;"
>       with self.cursor as c:
E       AttributeError: __enter__

database/import_manager.py:75: AttributeError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/import_class_tests.py::test_drop_import_table - AttributeError: ...
============================== 1 failed in 0.08s ===============================


__dunder__ methods are looked up on the class, and not the instance. eg.
len(my_list)

is equvalent:
my_list.__class__.__len__(my_list)

This is done to reduce the amount of memory allocation, and object (bound function) initialisations that python has to do.
However, this means you cannot monkey-patch dunder methods.
You will have to create a specialised class for your test, and get cursor() to return an instance of it.
eg.
import unittest.mock

class MockCursor:
    def __init__(self, execute):
        self.execute = execute
        self._enter_call_count = 0
        self._exit_calls = []

    def __enter__(self):
        self._enter_call_count += 1
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._exit_calls.append(unittest.mock.call(
            exc_type, exc_value, traceback
        ))
        return None

@pytest.fixture
def mock_cursor(mocker):
    mock_execute = mocker.MagicMock()
    return MockCursor(mock_execute)

@pytest.fixture
def mock_db(mocker, mock_cursor):
    """Fixture for setting up a mock database connection."""
    mock_db = mocker.Mock(spec=Importer)
    mock_db.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor
    return mock_db

Your test needs a little fine-tuning. This will at least get it to the assert statement:
def test_drop_import_table(mock_cursor, mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(Importer, 'cursor', mock_cursor)
    ...

Though I think that is in part because you do with self.cursor as c rather than with self.cursor() as c: in your sample test.

thanks for your answer.
I'll give this a go.

I think that is in part because you do with self.cursor as c rather than with self.cursor() as c: in your sample test.

What is it about, providing cursor as a property, that interferes with the tests working?

using your code as supplied, it is still erroring
It seems we are now returning a function rather than the expected Object.
        importer = Importer()  
        importer.create_import_table()    
>       drop_table_call = mock_db.cursor.return_value.execute.call_args_list[0]
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'
tests/cursor_tests.py:43: AttributeError

